# Install Docker from a DVD no network connection

Tags: docker, centos-7

I am trying to find a way to install docker-ce on a CentOS box with no internet connection (government box). I have gone down the dependency hole years ago while trying to install another package so this time I am trying to cover all my bases.

I found several commands which can show or download all the dependencies for each given package and I will list them below. But the result of each command is not the same as the other ones. There are some common packages, but not all the same. I was just wondering if someone could please help me figure out a way to download all the dependencies so I can burn them on a DVD and take it to the remote location and install Docker successfully. Thank you

```
repoquery --requires --resolve docker-ce
yum deplist docker-ce
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/home/test docker
```

Comment: First question... are you allowed to? Do you have the sysadmin's approval?

Comment: yes, I was told that I will have access, we'll see. Just want to be prepared

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repotrack`, see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50671/221985

I've just installed CentOS 7 Minimal, and have done the following:

#### Add the Docker Repository

As per the "[*Get Docker*](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-repository)" manual:

```
$ yum install -y yum-utils
$ yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
$ yum makecache
```

#### Download Packages for Docker

Note that `device-mapper-persistent-data` and `lvm2` are specified explicitly in the manual above.

The others were required as updates (discovered by trial and error). The key is a missing `Total download size:` line (or zero bytes).

```
$ mkdir ~/docker
$ cd ~/docker/
$ repotrack -a x86_64 -p "$(pwd)" device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2 docker-ce
$ repotrack -a x86_64 -p "$(pwd)" audit dracut-config-rescue dracut-network e2fsprogs \
    e2fsprogs-libs libss systemd-sysv
```

This downloaded 216 packages (~161 MB)... note that it included both the `i686` and `x86_64` architectures... the answer linked above addresses this if that's a problem for you.

#### Go Offline and Install

Using `yum` to install the RPMs will make use of `yum`'s dependency solver - *much* easier than running `rpm` by hand in the correct order...

```
$ cd ~/docker/
$ yum install --noplugins *.noarch.rpm *.x86_64.rpm
```

Then start docker, and away you go:

```
$ service docker start
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```